# Why is my route ignored for one below it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have code that specifies the following routes in my routes.rb:

```
concern :searchable do
  get "search(/:query)", controller: "search", action: :show, as: "search"
end

scope module: 'custom_domains', as: "custom_domain" do
   root to: "pages#show", id: "index"
   concerns :searchable

   get '/:id' => "pages#show", as: "page"

   match "*path" => "redirects#show", via: [ :get ], as: "redirect"
end

/                                                                        
/search(/:query)(.:format)       
/:id(.:format)                                                        
/*path(.:format)
```

When I try to visit `/search`, the route is skipped and catch all `*path` matches the route. I'm stumped. Routes are defined top to bottom and match in that order, so I would think that `/search` would be correct match. Do you know why this isn't the case?

Comment: I found a work around by changing `*path` to `(*path)`. I'm don't fully understand why this works, though. I think it has to do with how greed the pattern matcher is. If someone knows the reason, I'd love to hear it!